# Most efficient way of loading large amount of data on Firebase

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a simple viewpager with 2 fragments. One is for loading the newest posts and the other is loading top post, similar to the Reddit official app.

The way I currently load the Firebase data is to set obtain the snapshot through a singleValueListener and then sort after. The "new" tab doesn't require any Queries since it is already placed in order, however, for "top" it would need to order by score. I then load those data directly into RecyclerView.

Is there a more efficient way to loading the data? I currently have only a small database and it takes a while to load up, especially at the beginning. The only idea I have right now is to use Firebase's limitTo methods, however, that would not work for the "top" posts tab as it'll need all the data to work with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your code, so I can not comment on that. But from what you've described, the method you're using indeed is the most efficient one.

From my own experience, I can vouch that Firebase is blazingly fast. However, the delay you're experiencing right at the start is because Firebase needs to establish connection with the database in the beginning. Once the connection is established, updates and downloads are in real time ( only constrained to the amount of data you're editing and your network quality ). One thing that you can look into is enabling offline persistence, so that the users of your app are not shown a blank screen at app startup. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Comment: Thinking about it now, you're right. The slow loading time only occurs during the first load. Thanks for the information. I'll have a read about it now. My database only contains 20 post at the moment. But do you think with my current design pattern it will be able to handle and sort hundreds of post?

Comment: You should only load data that you show to the user. You're unlike to ever going to show hundreds of posts to the user, so you shouldn't load them. If you need to show a list of posts, you're likely only showing the title plus some other metadata. In such cases, create a separate list of this "list data" in your database and load that.

Comment: I really can't say about your data structure choice with this little information. However, as long as you follow Frank's advice, everything will be smooth.